# OpenCV library: low camera framerate, slow

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, frame-rate

I am using openCV library to detect objects (colored squares).
My problem is low framerate.
My device is 4 core Samsung galaxy S3.

This is part of my code that dramatically reduces the framerate:

```
public void morphOps(Mat filteredFrame)
{
    erosion_size = morphSeekBars[0].getRealProgress();
    dilation_size = morphSeekBars[1].getRealProgress();

    //create structuring element that will be used to "dilate" and "erode" image.       
    erodeElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement( Imgproc.MORPH_ERODE, new Size(2 * erosion_size + 1, 2 * erosion_size + 1), new Point(erosion_size, erosion_size));
    Imgproc.erode(filteredFrame, filteredFrame, erodeElement);

    //dilate with larger element so make sure object is nicely visible
    dilateElement = Imgproc.getStructuringElement( Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(2 * dilation_size + 1, 2 * dilation_size + 1), new Point(dilation_size/2, dilation_size/2));
    Imgproc.dilate(filteredFrame, filteredFrame, dilateElement);
    Imgproc.dilate(filteredFrame, filteredFrame, dilateElement);
}
```

As you can see I make one erode and two dilate operations, and on 640x480 resolution I get around 12 fps... Any ideas?

Comment: not a big improvement, but you could define your erodeelement outside morphOps()

Comment: I was thinking about that but it doesn't make any difference. Is it normal that it is slow, or it is only my case?

Comment: I once had an AR project with about 30FPS on an (now) older device, where I did much more operations on a single frame. So I suspect, that you could achieve much more than 12FPS.

Comment: The question is what was your camera resolution? And did you use morphological operations like erosion and dilation? Any ideas what can I do to improve framerate?

Comment: The display resolution was min 800 x 480 I believe. Yes I did erode and dilate, that is quite common.